# What is stuff beyond .data section in Assembly?

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to understand how exactly assembly code lay out to memory space. I wrote a simple assembly code which contains just a few lines of instruction and .data section. When I inspected it with GDB, I saw more stuff beyond data section which I couldn't see with objdump -section-header command. Below is output from gdb.

```
(gdb) x/100x &data
0x804909c <data>:   0x03020100  0x07060504  0x0b0a0908  0x050e0d0c
0x80490ac <other>:  0x00000000  0x6d79732e  0x00626174  0x7274732e
0x80490bc:  0x00626174  0x7368732e  0x61747274  0x742e0062
0x80490cc:  0x00747865  0x7461642e  0x00000061  0x00000000
0x80490dc:  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x80490ec:  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x80490fc:  0x00000000  0x0000001b  0x00000001  0x00000006
0x804910c:  0x08048074  0x00000074  0x00000027  0x00000000
0x804911c:  0x00000000  0x00000004  0x00000000  0x00000021
```

The end of .data section is 0x80490af, but as you can see there are more stuffs beyond .data section which I have no clue whatsoever. What exactly are they? Are they just junk or something else? What will happen if I try to access a memory beyond .data section?

Comment: What about a linker map file? It will tell you what is in the .data section, e.g. variables from start-up code or so.

Comment: Can I verify that with objdump or similar tools?

Comment: Probably but you need debugging information then. You have to know the name of the variables that are in the data segment to know what they are.

Comment: "The end of .data section is 0x80490af" The end of this `.data` section is `0x80490ab.`

Comment: @EJP no there's variable name other which holds 3 bytes of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the system loads your file into memory, it does not stop reading at the end of the data section because there is no reason to, and it is more efficient not to. Since the executable says nothing is there, the code should not access it, so putting something there does not matter. It is more efficient because the system can use pages from the file system cache instead of copying the data, which saves physical memory and avoids a copy.

That being said, that is the content of the executable file after the data section on disk. If you look at the beginning of that extra data as strings, you will see that it is the names of sections in the file (the first two are ".symtab" and ".strtab"). After that comes other information from the file. This is data used by the linker or loader to parse the file, which just happens to have been placed in memory.

Comment: another question is, let's say I want to compare some value with the value on data section. And if condition does not check the end of data and keep comparing values beyond data section, there is no guaranteed to satisfy that condition right?

Comment: Right. If you read past the end of the data section, it is impossible to be sure what will be there. There might even be nothing there, which would cause a segfault.